# Differential equations with vectors

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, vector-analysis

I saw some equations like that $\operatorname{grad}(y(x,y,z)) + y(x,y,z) = 0.$
How can we solve it? What is this kind of differential equation called?

For example I found that:

$$\frac{\partial\rho}{\partial t}+\nabla\cdot(\rho\mathbf{V})=0. $$

Comment: This equation doesn't make sense at the moment, because $\operatorname{grad}(y)$ is a completely different kind of mathematical object (vector) from $y$ (scalar). How is that addition defined?

Comment: I mean differential equations with a nabla, sorry I am a bit confused

Comment: $grady$ is a vector and $y$ is a scalar...how do you add these?Do you mean something else?

Comment: $\operatorname{grad}(y)=\nabla y;$ they're the same thing. Do you have an exact question you can type up?

Comment: I show you an example I found: https://wikimedia.org/api/rest_v1/media/math/render/svg/e062d60ac274c21120a593fd8aacfebbe22b07fb

Comment: These are called partial differential equations. This one looks linear, and might well be solvable. I assume $\rho$ is a function of spatial variables? What is $\mathbf{V}?$

Comment: $\mathbf{V}$ is a vector and the $\nabla\cdot$ is the divergence. This particular equation is an advection equation, which can be solved by the method of characteristics

Comment: ρ is the volumic mass and V is the velocity